# How do I install playbin2 plugins for gstreamer on windows

Tags: windows, gstreamer, playbin2

I am trying to run the tutorials for gstreamer proposed [here](http://docs.gstreamer.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=327735)
and running into [the problem described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923306/gstreamer-with-visual-c-express-2010-tutorial-1) .My case is that I probably have not plugins for playbin2 installed .My problem is how do I get them installed? I have downloaded and installed gstreamer( the devel version ) and I have successfully linked against the libraries as suggested [here](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows) but can't find anything related to playbin2 .Can anyone suggest a way I can make my application aware of the playbin2 plugins?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at gstreamer.com, there is notice on the top of the page referring to the official gstreamer project page -> gstreamer.freedesktop.org.

These tutorials are for 0.10 version that is now obsolete and unmantained. For example, in 1.0 playbin2 was renamed to playbin.

I'd recommend getting the official 1.0 releases directly from gstreamer.freedesktop.org and starting from there.

Comment: I installed gsreamer 1.0 and running into the problem described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988393/how-do-i-get-the-gstreamer-plugins-windows  I would be glad if you helped .Thanks

Comment: This link http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows suggests that plugins are installed in C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0  by default but when I set my GST_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable to that path gst_element_factory_make ("fakesrc", "source") still returns NULL .

Comment: Running the commands here : http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/faq/html/chapter-using.html I can see that my installation is doing fine .The problem is getting my c++ application executable to know where to look for these plugins .