# How do I get the gstreamer plugins--windows

Tags: plugins, gstreamer

I now installed gstreamer 1.0 from gstreamer.freedesktop.org and going through [their tutorials.](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-elements-create.html)

I am facing a problem though, my gst_element_factory_make() calls are failing and I think it is the
plugin path problem as suggested here : [Gstreamer : gst_element_factory_make() : always fail and return NULL : Qt5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878125/gstreamer-gst-element-factory-make-always-fail-and-return-null-qt5)

But I can't find a plugin
directory in my gstreamer install directory .Can anyone suggest how I can get those plugins so I can set the path? Do I need to download them separately?
(A link would be helpful if any).I am new to gstreamer and multimedia programming in general. I apologize if this is obvious.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where does the plugins got installed for your system (windows, right?). You can search for the folder that has the plugin libs. Search for libgstplayback.so/.dll or libgstcoreelements.so/.dll and you should find it. It is likely under the folder you selected for installation but I don't know what is the default.

Then just use the GST_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable to point to that and run your application.

Comment: Thanks ,I found it to be in C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib\gstreamer-1.0 for my system just in case somebody else runs in the same hussle.I should also mention that the path setting took effect after I restarted my system .