# GStreamer Basic Tutorial 1 Visual Studio 2010 C++

Tags: windows-7, gstreamer, playbin2

Hi I am having some issues with gstreamer-0.10 on Windows 7 64bit (using 32 bit gstreamer).

Please see code below for tutorial 1 (modified for VS2010):

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  // Added GError to catch pipeline problems?
  // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923306/gstreamer-with-visual-c-express-2010-tutorial-1
  GError **errorMsg = NULL;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("playbin2 uri=http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", errorMsg);
  // pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("playbin uri=http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", errorMsg);
  // pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("playbin2 uri=http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", NULL);
  // pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("playbin uri=http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", NULL);
  // pipeline = gst_parse_launch ("videotestsrc ! autovideosink", errorMsg);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);

  /* MSVC Compiler is more strict with enum type casting hence the (GstMessageType) cast on the second parameter */
  msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, (GstMessageType)(GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS));
  // msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Free resources */
  if (msg != NULL)
    gst_message_unref (msg);
    gst_object_unref (bus);
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles fine however I receive the below output at runtime:

```
(basic-tutorial-1_debug.exe:8700): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_set_state:
 assertion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(basic-tutorial-1_debug.exe:8700): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_bus: a
ssertion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(basic-tutorial-1_debug.exe:8700): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bus_timed_pop_filt
ered: assertion `GST_IS_BUS (bus)' failed

(basic-tutorial-1_debug.exe:8700): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: asse
rtion `object != NULL' failed

(basic-tutorial-1_debug.exe:8700): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_set_state:
 assertion `GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

(basic-tutorial-1_debug.exe:8700): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_object_unref: asse
rtion `object != NULL' failed
```

I also used --gst-debug-level=4 (selected output below):

```
it_check: initialized GStreamer successfully
0:00:00.358921084  8236   004D5000 INFO            GST_PIPELINE gstparse.c:334:g
st_parse_launch_full: parsing pipeline description 'playbin2 uri=http://docs.gst
reamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm'
0:00:00.368644038  8236   004D5000 DEBUG           GST_PIPELINE parse.l:107:priv
_gst_parse_yylex: flex: IDENTIFIER: playbin2
0:00:00.375062362  8236   004D5000 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactor
y.c:467:gst_element_factory_make: no such element factory "playbin2"!
0:00:00.381743480  8236   004D5000 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE ./grammar.y:661:
priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "playbin2"
0:00:00.387568465  8236   004D5000 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE ./grammar.y:929:
priv_gst_parse_launch: Unrecoverable syntax error while parsing pipeline playbin
2 uri=http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm
```

I also tried to rename 'playbin2' to 'playbin' as well as some more regular pipelines (which work on the command line).

I would be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Can you make the following change to your error handling so we can see where gst_parse_launch is failing?   
 GError* error = NULL;
 pipeline = gst_parse_launch("...", &error);
 iff(pipeline == NULL || error != NULL) {
  printf("Parse Error: %s\n", error->message);
 }

Comment: `Parse Error: no element "playbin2"` - Fixed this by setting the environment variable GST_PLUGIN_PATH to my lib location C:\gstreamer-sdk\0.10\x86\lib\gstreamer-0.10. Many thanks @mpr : )

Comment: Same issues, same solutions. Thanks guys.

Comment: My window is still not showing. Any ideas?